# WebDav Protocol VS HTTP Protocol

Tags: sockets, webdav, http-protocols

In what way WebDAV protocol is better than HTTP protocol in terms of upload.

Is there comparison between Socket Upload protocol and WebDav Upload protocol?

Comment: [WebDAV is an extension of HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV), the question requires rethought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebDav is an extension of the HTTP protocol. Like AJAX for PHP. The upload progess is much more faster and easy to setup in a big company network than HTTP regular uploads.

A WebDAV-Server supports SSL(Secure Sockets Layer) too. You can upload via HTTP-POST directorys.

Sockets are permanently connected to the destination until the task is done.

Answer (score -2):

WebDAV upload uses PUT, which is the same as in HTTP. So there really is no difference.